# Airflow: how to use xcom_push and xcom_pull in non-PythonOperator

Tags: airflow

I see a lot of examples on how to use `xcom_push` and `xcom_pull` with PythonOperators in Airflow.

I need to do `xcom_pull` from a *non-PythonOperator* class and couldn't find how to do it.

Any pointer or example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access XCom variables from within templated fields. For example, to read from XCom:

```
myOperator = MyOperator(
    message="Operation result: {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=['task1', 'task2'], key='result_status') }}",
    ...
```

It is also possible to not specify task to get all XCom pushes within one DagRun with the same key name

```
myOperator = MyOperator(
    message="Warning status: {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=None, key='warning_status') }}",
    ...
```

would return an array.

Comment: This doesn't address pushing from a non-PythonOperator.

Comment: Correct. In my version of the question, only "I need to do xcom_pull from a non-PythonOperator" was asked.

Answer (score 4):

#### From inside an operator's `execute` method:

Push:

```py
self.xcom_push(context, key, value)
```

Pull:

```py
self.xcom_pull(context, key=key)
```

#### If you have a task instance:

Push:

```py
context["ti"].xcom_push(key, value)
```

Pull:

```py
context["ti"].xcom_pull(key=key)
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate this answer by mentioning, where these lines can be added?

Comment: Ok, added more info.