# Passing return value from operator to following operator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to give a string list to the `source_objects` field for the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` but with the following code I get an error:

> string indices must be integers, not unicode

**Things I don't know :**

- How do I get the `return` value of the `get_file_name` with an XCOM at the DAG scope ?
- How do I call the `xcom_pull` function at the DAG scope without having to provide a context? It seemed to me that task instances do not need to provide a context.

**Things I thought of :**

- Rewrite the operator and take an XCOM as argument

**The thing I want to do :**

- I want to be able to call the operator

Also, it seems that some of the operator's fields use a feature called `templated_field`, what's the mechanism behind the template fields? Isn't just for `PythonOperator` and `BashOperator`?

And a last one, why does `PythonOperator` does not return a `TaskInstance`?

```
with DAG('bq_load_file_from_cloud_function', default_args=default_args) as dag:

    def get_file_name_from_conf(ds, **kwargs):
        fileName = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['fileName']
        return [fileName]

    get_file_name = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_file_name',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_file_name_from_conf)

    bq_load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_load', 
        bucket='src_bucket', 
        #source_objects=['data.csv'], 
        source_objects=get_file_name.xcom_pull(context='', task_ids='get_file_name'), 
        destination_project_dataset_table='project:dataset.table', 
        write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY')

    bq_load.set_upstream(get_file_name)
```

I'm kind of new to Python and Airflow. These kinds of things are supposed to be trivial I guess. I'm sure there's something I misunderstood here.

Comment: This could hint into the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581363/airflow-how-to-use-xcom-push-and-xcom-pull-in-non-pythonoperator/51587771#51587771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tests, I came up with this solution, thanks to tobi6 for his comment which pointed me in the right direction. I had to use the **template_fields** feature.

When I tried to return a list with a single string, I had concatenation errors, so I had to return a single string in my XCOM and the surround the template call to XCOM with brackets to make the result a list.

Here's the final code :

```
with DAG('bq_load_file_from_cloud_function', default_args=default_args) as dag:

    def get_file_name_from_conf(ds, **kwargs):
        return kwargs['dag_run'].conf['fileName']

    get_file_name = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_file_name',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_file_name_from_conf)

    bq_load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_load', 
        bucket='src_bucket', 
        source_objects=["{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_file_name') }}"],
        destination_project_dataset_table='project:dataset.table', 
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')

    bq_load.set_upstream(get_file_name)
```