# Extract filename from the previous stage - Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a task where I save a file that has the format 'account_{year}_{month}.csv to a Google Cloud storage - I am using PythonOperator. For example, this month file is called account_2023_06. Next month, it will be named 'account_2023_07'.

Then, in the next step, I am supposed to retrieve that newly uploaded file from the Cloud Storage and save it as a BigQuery table:

```
    dataset_CS_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id = "dataset_CS_BQ",
        bucket = BUCKET_accounts_historical,
        source_objects =[....csv]
```

My challenge is that I cannot figure out what source_objects  to use in source_objects as the file name will change every month. The options I could think of are not to add {year} and {month} when naming the file OR maybe use extract the latest modified file in the folder in the bucket and then somehow pass the file name, but it will be over-simplification as it is desirable to have yyyy_mm as a part of the file name.

Can you, please, re-direct me to some reading/advise me on how I could complete it?

Update:
Resolved by passing the file name to:

```
def accounts(**kwargs):
    auth = (kwargs['username'], kwargs['password'])
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ...
    #Instantiate cloud storage
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_accounts_historical_sl)
    
    #Saving to GCS
    path = "/accounts/"+ 'account_'+str(yr)+'_'+str(mnth)+'.csv'
    ti.xcom_push(key = 'path' , value = path)
```

Then, added provide_context to the task itself:

```
    download_dataset_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="download_dataset_task",
            python_callable=accounts,
            provide_context=True,
    )
```

Finally, retrieved the stored xcom value with:

```
    dataset_CS_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id = "dataset_CS_BQ",
        bucket = BUCKET_accounts_historical,
        source_objects =["{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='path') }}"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updates for the solution but the related Stack questions are:

1. [Passing return value from operator to following operator in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892190/passing-return-value-from-operator-to-following-operator-in-airflow)
2. [Airflow: how to use xcom_push and xcom_pull in non-PythonOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581363/airflow-how-to-use-xcom-push-and-xcom-pull-in-non-pythonoperator/51587771#51587771)
3. [GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator source_objects to receive list via XCom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092097/googlecloudstoragetobigqueryoperator-source-objects-to-receive-list-via-xcom)
4. [Airflow - How to pass xcom variable into Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059161/airflow-how-to-pass-xcom-variable-into-python-function)