# Using xcom_push and xcom_pull in python file that called from BashOperator

Tags: airflow

I saw some similar questions about it (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638295/i-cant-xcom-push-an-arguments-through-bashoperator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581363/airflow-how-to-use-xcom-push-and-xcom-pull-in-non-pythonoperator)) but none of them answer this quesiton.

I want to run some python file with BashOperator.
Like this:

```
my_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        bash_command='python3 /opt/airflow/dags/programs/my_task.py',
    )
```

Is there a way I can call `xcom_push` and `xcom_pull` from `my_task.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify it to `PythonOperator` or pass arguments to the script through bash command using Jinja syntax.

1. PythonOperator

   ```py
   from programs.my_task import my_function

   my_task = PythonOperator(
       task_id='my_task',
       python_callable=my_function,
   )
   ```

   my_task.py

   ```py
   def my_function(**context):
       xcom_value = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task'))

       context['ti'].xcom_push(key='key', value='value') # this one is pushed to xcom

       return "xcom_push_value" # this value is also stored to xcom (xcom_push).
   ```
2. Pass arguments to the python script

   ```py
   my_task = BashOperator(
       task_id='my_task',
       bash_command='python3 /opt/airflow/dags/programs/my_task.py {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="previous_task") }}'
   )
   ```

   my_task.py

   ```py
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       xcom_pulled_value = sys.argv[1]

       print("xcom_push_value") # last line of stdout is stored to xcom.
   ```

   Alternatively, with this approach, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: thank you very much! But if I want to use the bashOperator, with your solution I can push only one value. I want to push multiple values.

Comment: It depends on how much you want to push.  If it is a few and the value is structured, you _could_ print in a csv style like `print("hello,world,123")` and in your successor operator split the csv.  It is not that clean approach, though.

Comment: And if variables is more than just a few, you probably want to use either `PythonOperator` or custom intermediate data storage (ie file?).

Comment: Understood, So the answer is that we can't push more than once. But we can manually do some workaround.

Comment: With `BashOperator`, yes, it is limited. With `PythonOperator` you can add multiple values. I'm not sure if you noticed, but I updated my answer to show the way to do `xcom_push` using context. That way, you can associate multiple values to unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use xcoms in a `BashOperator` and the desire is to pass the arguments to a python script from the xcoms, then I would suggest adding some `argparse` arguments to the python script then using named arguments and Jinja templating the `bash_command`. So something like this:

```py
# Assuming you already xcom pushed the variable as "my_xcom_variable"

my_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        bash_command='python3 /opt/airflow/dags/programs/my_task.py --arg1={{ ti.xcom_pull(key="my_xcom_variable") }}',
    )
```

Then if you are unfamiliar with `argparse` you can add it at the end of the python script like so:

```py
# ^^^ The rest of your program is up here ^^^
# I have no idea what your python script is,
# just assuming your main program is a function called main_program()
# add as many arguments as you want and name them whatever you want

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument('--arg1')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main_program(args_from_the_outside=args.arg1)
```